# Ember - Render products through different templates based on a value in the array

Tags: json, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have simplified my app for the purposes of this question. I am just starting to get my head around Ember, and I am not yet doing things as efficiently as it can be done, I am sure.

I am looking for a way to use a different template for entries with certain characteristics. Let me explain:

I have a nested route as follows:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('products', function() {
        this.resource('product', { path: '/:product_id' });
    });
});
```

and a JSON file like this:

```
{"product": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Bicycle",
      "description": "A nice red bicycle that you can ride on.",
      "display": "textonly"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Bus",
      "description": "A big bus that many people can ride on."
      "display": "bigblocks"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Airplane",
      "description": "You can fly in this to get to your destination faster",
      "display": "textonly"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, I have added a property to my JSON that determines how the product entries should be displayed.

Now, my html templates looks like this:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='products'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-3'>
            <div class='list-group'>
                {{#each}}
                    {{#link-to 'product' this classNames='list-group-item'}}
                        {{title}}
                    {{/link-to}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9'>
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='product'>
    <div class ='row'>
        <div class ='col-md-9'>
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</script>
```

My app currently renders like this:

[image]

[image]

Now, what I want to do, is render some products through a different template (or view or component or whatever is the best for the job), so that when `"display": "bigblocks"` the product is rendered slightly different than for when `"display": "textonly"` like so:

[image]

So in effect, I want to have many JSON entries, and render them differently based on their 'display' value in the JSON file.

I am just looking for a very simple way to do this for now, maybe an IF statement or something similar, just so I can get my head around how this could be done.

Thanks alot, and please ask for more info if required :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using a calculated property on your controller and conditional logic within your template.

Include the following calculated property in your product controller:

```
isDisplayTextOnly: function(){
    return this.get('display') === 'textonly';
}.property('model.display')
```

Add conditional logic to your product template so that it will display in varying formats depending on the value calculated in the controller:

```
{{#if isDisplayTextOnly}}
    <!-- What you want displayed when  "display" == "textonly" -->
{{else}}
    <!-- What you want displayed when  "display" == "bigblocks" or anything else -->
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Components allow you to specify `templateName`. So, you can compute template name based on the value of `display` property as follows:

```
App.XDisplayComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: "",
  templateName: function(){
    return this.get('item.display'); 
  }.property('item'),
});
```

And you would use the component as follows:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
      {{#each item in model}}
        <li>{{item.name}} {{ x-display item=item}} </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

See a working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/baminu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up going with this method, but Oren's also worked :)